# HTTP Headers Information

Tags: php, http-headers

```
echo phpinfo();
```

I am looking at the "HTTP Headers Information", but I can't find headers like:

```
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Also HTTP Response Headers:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

How do I set these variables?

Comment: Accept-* headers are Request headers, not Response headers. When you are making an HTTP response, they are *input* not output. You can't set them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set headers with [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function

Comment: Only Response headers though.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code snippet:

```
header('Accept-Language :en-US,en;q=0.8');
```

for more information:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

and also, if you want to analyze the headers coming in, or going out you should take a look at this program:

http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: That, however, is nonsense. There is no HTTP Response Accept-Language header. It is a Request header.

Answer (score 0):

To set the response headers use header():
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

To retrieve the request headers use getallheaders():
http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: Actually I am using the header header('Content-type: application/xml')